# NonlinearModelFit is going way past best values to values that don't work

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have a model that I want to fit experimental data to:

```
model[t2_?NumericQ, cr_?NumericQ, c11_?NumericQ, c21_?NumericQ, 
c31_?NumericQ, c12_?NumericQ, c22_?NumericQ, c32_?NumericQ] := (
0.73*(1 - Exp[-
     NIntegrate[
      If[(Tmelt - cr*t) < Tm1, 
       If[(Tmelt - cr*t) > Tg, 
        c11*10^10*(Tmelt - cr*t)*
         Exp[(-c21*1000)/((Tmelt - cr*t) - Tg + 51.6) - (
           c31*10^7)/((Tmelt - cr*t)*(Tm1 - (Tmelt - cr*t))^2)], 
        0.], 0.], {t, 1, t2}]^n1])
+ 0.27*(1 - Exp[-
     NIntegrate[
      If[(Tmelt - cr*t) < Tm2, 
       If[(Tmelt - cr*t) > Tg, 
        c12*10^10*(Tmelt - cr*t)*
         Exp[(-c22*1000)/((Tmelt - cr*t) - Tg + 51.6) - (
           c32*10^7)/((Tmelt - cr*t)*(Tm2 - (Tmelt - cr*t))^2)], 
        0.], 0.], {t, 1., t2}]^n2])
);
```

It's pretty complicated but I see no reason mathematica cant do it numerically. Essentially the code is 1-Exp[Integral[k] where k varies exponentially with time such that you can't find the indefinite integral. c11-c-32 are the fitting parameters and everything else is constant except t and cr which are my independent variables.

```
n1 = 2.5;
Tg = 144. + 273.15;
Tm1 = 593.;
n2 = 1.5;
Tm2 = 615.;
Tmelt = 375 + 273.15;
```

To start, I tired making data using the model with a little bit of variance:

```
data = Table[{t2, 55.8/60, 
model[t2, 55.8/60., 2.08, 4.05, 1.8, 2.08,7.6, .32]
*(1. + RandomReal[{-1., 1.}]*0.00001)}
,{t2, 2.,150.}];
```

But when I try to fit the data it goes to crazy values including negative values which wont work with the model

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, 
model[t2, cr, c11, c21, c31, c12, c22,c32],
{{c11, 2.08}, {c21, 4.05}, {c31, 1.8}, {c12, 2.08}, {c22,7.6}, {c32, .32}},
{t2, cr}];
```

I have no idea why it wont just give me the values back. Does it need some level of accuracy or it starts making crazy guesses? The model is sigmoidal and I think the parameters mostly move/stretch the graph along the x axis so maybe its an issue where changing them a little moves the graph and none of the points are even close?

Comment: I would expect pretty much any nonlinear iterative algorithm to go off the rails unless suitable constraints are given. In your particular case, you might be interested in putting your constraint of positive parameters, e.g. `NonlinearModelFit[data, {model[t2, cr, c11, c21, c31, c12, c22, c32], c11 > 0 && c21 > 0}, {{c11, 2.08}, {c21, 4.05}, {c31, 1.8}, {c12, 2.08}, {c22,7.6}, {c32, .32}}, {t2, cr}]`

Comment: Does plotting the generated data result in anything interesting?  The following looks almost featureless:  `ListPointPlot3D[data]`.  Might that be the problem?